# How can I recursively copy files by file extension?

Tags: command-line, files, find, cp

I would like to copy all files with a certain extension that are in sub directories to a different folder. I don't want to maintain the directory structure, I just want to copy all files found to a different folder.

I used this command to do it:

```
cp `find . -name "*.aac"` /media/moasad/New\ Volume/Media\ files/Avengers/Aud/aac/
```

However, I noticed that If it runs into folders or files with spaces in them the `cp` function doesn't know what to do and I get an error something like this:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘./Temporary_Items/martin/Problem’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘Files/nav-YCA136843.aac’: No such file or directory
```

Notice that its one file: `./Temporary_Items/martin/Problem Files/nav-YCA136843.aac`

But because of the space in "Problem Files", it's confused.

Comment: As your google is broken ... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces and http://superuser.com/questions/80033/command-line-wizardry-spaces-in-file-names-with-find-grep-xargs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `-exec` option of `find` command

```
find . -iname '*.acc' -exec cp {} <dest folder> \;
```

Comment: Or `... -exec cp -t <dest folder> {} +`, so that it copies many files together.