# Copy a specific file command

Tags: command-line, copy

How can I copy files  with extension .ORF from a director and all it's sub-directors to a different director. i.e: I have home/Pictures and it's sub-directories and I want to copy only the files  with .ORF extension to home/TempPictures

I want to specify that I have had a look already here and on a lot of other sites and I haven't find the answer I look for...

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, the lack of my Linux knowledge it doesn't help me to follow the answers in the question [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/691588/how-can-i-recursively-copy-files-by-file-extension),so I would much appreciate if someone can give me an answer with my folders home/Pictures and home/TempPictures.

Comment: I have found the answer in another question. I have used this : find /home/cosmin/Pictures/ -type f -name '*.ORF' -exec cp '{}' /home/cosmin/TempPictures/ \; and it worked well.